# Detect vertical scroll has already ended and the user is pulling

Tags: java, android, pull-to-refresh, android-nestedscrollview, coordinator-layout

How to detect when user has already reached the end of `NestedScrollView` and in his current scroll attempt motion is pulling?

I've tried some patterns with detecting end scroll but that's far from what I am searching to achieve.

What I came to as well was that I can override public class  `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` and play with scroll methods however I am happy with current `@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` and I am not quite sure how to proceed.

**view structure**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|enterAlways" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Anybody familiar with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the end of **NestedScrollView** like that

```
svProduct.getViewTreeObserver()
        .addOnScrollChangedListener(() -> {
          View view = svProduct.getChildAt(svProduct.getChildCount() - 1);
          int diff = (view.getBottom() - (svProduct.getHeight() + svProduct.getScrollY()));
          if (diff == 0) {
            // reached to bottom 
          }
        });
```